# How to add scale to bar plot inside table

Tags: tables

I have following table with bar plot inside. I would like to add scale (x axis) at bottom of bars.

Can anyone guide me how can I achieve that in LaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\mybar#1{%%
  #1s & {\color{red}\rule{#1cm}{8pt}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{$\rhd$ }lrl}
Loop at line 151 in divergence  & \mybar{3.420}\\
Loop at line 1071 in radiation  & \mybar{3.270}\\
scalar face value               & \mybar{3.090}\\
Loop at line 102 in get         & \mybar{1.700}\\
get sensible enthalpy           & \mybar{1.250}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean that the figures `3.420` etc. should appear at the bottom?

Comment: No. I would like to put xaxis at the bottom. Not for each bar.

Comment: Ok, I'll delete my answer then because your question is unclear and my answer useless then

Answer (score 1):

Hers is a quick and dirty answer using TikZ, the difficulty imho is to avoid an offset of the axis due to the width of the number. 
Maybe some TikZ guru will find a cleaner way to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\mybar#1{%%
  #1s & {\color{red}\rule{#1cm}{8pt}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{$\rhd$ }lrl}
Loop at line 151 in divergence  & \mybar{3.420}\\
Loop at line 1071 in radiation  & \mybar{3.270}\\
 using tikzscalar face value               & \mybar{3.090}\\
Loop at line 102 in get         & \mybar{1.700}\\
get sensible enthalpy           & \mybar{1.250}\\
&& \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}
      \draw[thin] (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.1);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}    
      \node at ({\x+0.15}, {0-0.1}) [below] {\x};
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Thats awesome. Can I change the scale to mm from cm? Will it change the tikz scale accordingly?

Comment: You will have to check it. The default TikZ unit is 1cm, but if necessary you can change it either with the scale parameter (`\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]`) or with defining explicitly the size of the unit vector for each axis independently (for example `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=1.5cm]`)

Comment: I did realize that the axis labels are shifted towards right. Can I get them in center position where the tick marks are? Thanks.

Comment: @3573959 the short answer is not this way ! That is what I try to explain in my answer and that is why I called it dirty. But perhaps someone will come up with a better answer.

Comment: how are you guys taking theese transparent TeX results? I'm always creating a screenshot of my pdf which isn't background-free