# How to add axis to bar plot inside table

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to add scale (xaxis) to table. Here is the code from DRi ([How to add scale to bar plot inside table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245023/how-to-add-scale-to-bar-plot-inside-table-latex?answertab=active#tab-top)).

I did realize that the axis labels are shifted towards right. Can I get them in center position where the tick marks are?

Or is there any another way to put scale at bottom?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\mybar#1{%%
  #1s & {\color{red}\rule{#1cm}{8pt}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{$\rhd$ }lrl}
Loop at line 151 in divergence  & \mybar{3.420}\\
Loop at line 1071 in radiation  & \mybar{3.270}\\
using tikzscalar face value               & \mybar{3.090}\\
Loop at line 102 in get         & \mybar{1.700}\\
get sensible enthalpy           & \mybar{1.250}\\
&& \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}
     \draw[thin] (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.1);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}    
     \node at ({\x+0.15}, {0-0.1}) [below] {\x};
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Here is the output]

Comment: If you want the numbers, 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 right below the markings, replace `\node at ({\x+0.15}, {0-0.1}) [below] {\x};` with  `\node at (\x, -0.1) [below] {\x};`, or did I misinterpret your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the final `\node` command from `\node at ({\x+0.15},....)...` to `\node at ({\x},...)...` and add a `trim left` to this `tikzpicture`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\mybar#1{%%
  #1s & {\color{red}\rule{#1cm}{8pt}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{$\rhd$ }lrl}
Loop at line 151 in divergence  &\mybar{3.420}\\
Loop at line 1071 in radiation  &\mybar{3.270}\\
using tikzscalar face value               &\mybar{3.090}\\
Loop at line 102 in get         &\mybar{1.700}\\
get sensible enthalpy           &\mybar{1.250}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&&\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}
     \draw[thin] (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.1);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}    
     \node at ({\x}, {0-0.1}) [below] {\x};
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Without the `trim left`, the left most point of the scale is the left of the `0` character, so this image is shifted to the right.  `trim left` make sure the left mose edge of the picture corresponds to the `x=0` coordinate in the picture.

As indicated by Zarko, I have also added `\multicolumn` code to remove the spurious triangle marker on the final line.

Comment: In the last row (to my taste) I will add for first two column a  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  for eliminate spurius $\rhd$ and coordinate of node for ticks simplified as suggested Grimler in his/her comment.

Comment: @Zarko Indeed - I had seen that and forgot to go back and change it.  Answer updated.